# Is there any way to see names of 'fields' in React multiple state with React DevTools when using 'useState' hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've been learning/experimenting with React hooks.  When I go to inspect the values of the current state of a component using React DevTools in Chrome, I see the state fine, but the actual 'fields' -- that is, the state variables that are being updated by the individual `useState` hooks -- don't have any name associated with them.  Instead, I see, for example, several strings, a couple of booleans, etc.  I can generally figure out what's going on, but this seems problematic -- I'd like to be able to see *which* what the state variable's name is.

For instance, if I have something like

```
const [doughnuts, setDoughnuts] = useState(24)
```

When I look in React DevTools I'd like to see something like `doughnuts: number : 24', instead of just 'number: 24'.

Am I missing some setting somewhere, or some technique to turn on this ability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not missing anything and you can't change this behaviour. This is how React deals with multiple state.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation.

One way to avoid this problem is to use a single State Hook which creates a single state including all the data.

`const [state, setState] = useState({doughnuts: 24, key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'});`

In this case the state is stored in a single object and each value is associated with a key.

Take a look at this: [Should I use one or many state variables?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables)

A compound state is hard to manage, but there is a tool which can help you with that: [useReducer Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Comment: Don't advice to use `useState()` for complex object state, instead use `useReducer()` would save your time from unnecessary headaches.

Comment: IMHO forcing the use of a single State Hook just to render easier the debugging of a react component doesn't seem a solid reason. Be aware that React team suggests: _However, **we recommend to split state into multiple state variables based on which values tend to change together**_. (...) _It makes it easy to later extract some related logic into a custom Hook_. (Cited from the same source @chumakoff suggested: Should I use one or many state variables?)

Answer (score 60):

##### Finally react team listened to us

The recent introduction of parsing custom hooks in react dev tools option might help
.

###### Before parsing ( before clicking the magic button in custom hooks card )

[image]

.
[image]
.

###### After parsing ( clicking the magic button in the top right )

[image]

Comment: Please don't use remotely hosted image's in Q or Answer, all images are gone & the answer is not understandable

Comment: Where is the magic button? I can't find it in my react devtools panel

Comment: In the screenshot there is magic-wand button in the right  hand button

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work with nextjs and remix

Comment: nothing happens - I use 'nx'

Answer (score 29):

Some approaches not mentioned in the other answers:

1. Use the following:([suggested by Oleh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57659640/is-there-any-way-to-see-names-of-fields-in-react-multiple-state-with-react-dev#comment103161645_57659769))

```
const [{ item }, setItem] = useState({ item: 2 });
```

You could also wrap the `useState` function so that, based on the shape of the initial value, the `setItem` function it returns auto-converts from the passed value itself into an object with the correct (wrapper) shape.

2. Create a new `useStateWithLabel` function:

```
function useStateWithLabel(initialValue, name) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
    useDebugValue(`${name}: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
    return [value, setValue];
}
```

It's based on the `useDebugValue` function [described here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usedebugvalue).

Usage:

```
const [item, setItem] = useStateWithLabel(2, "item");
```

Comment: For object, use this: `useDebugValue(name + ":" + JSON.stringify(value));`

Comment: @Ayan Good point; edited the answer to use `JSON.stringify`, since that works for both primitives and objects.

Answer (score 5):

When you do the following operation

```
const [item, setItem] = useSate(2)
```

You're using `destructuring assignment` in an `array` a type which does not contain a `key` like an `object`. You're just creating an `alias` to access the first element of the array returned by `useState`. If you do something like this

```
const [item, setItem] = useState({value: 2})
```

You will be able to see `value: 2` in your dev-tools, cause it reflects the current state of that hook at a certain point of time.

Each time you call a Hook, it gets isolated local state within the currently executing component based on the previous value, so the identifier attributed by you (`item`) will only be scoped to that render cycle, but it doesn't mean that `React` reference is using the same identifier.

Comment: what if we do `const [{ item }, setItem] = useState({ item: 2 });`
to avoid having additional names and dev tools will have something to show us

Comment: @Oleh It seems like that would work, neat idea. You could also wrap the `useState` function so that, based on the shape of the initial value, the `setItem` function it returns auto-converts from the value itself into an object with the correct (wrapper) shape.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `useDebugState` hook from [use-named-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-named-state) package.

```
import { useDebugState } from "use-named-state";
const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useDebugState("counter", 0);

  return <button onClick={(prevCount) => prevCount + 1}>{counter}</button>;
};
```

It internally uses `useDebugValue` hook from react (method suggested by @Venryx)

Answer (score 0):

[Check this checkbox][1]

[1]: [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sg0j.png)

This works if checked hook names from source

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).