# Chrome Dev Tools Shows all useState hooks with the name 'State'

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, react-hooks

I am trying to inspect a React Hooks component in Dev Tools, but regardless of component, all my useState hooks show up as:

```
Hooks

State: false
State: null
Effect: fn()
```

The `false` values are correct, but I can't figure out which hook is which since for some reason they won't display the hook variable name.

Here is how I set up each hook:

`const [myHook, setMyHook] = useState(false);`

Comment: Looks like this is default behaviour unfortunately...
https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/1334

Answer (score 4):

See *[Is there any way to see names of 'fields' in React multiple state with React DevTools when using 'useState' hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57659640/is-there-any-way-to-see-names-of-fields-in-react-multiple-state-with-react-dev/58579953#58579953)*:

> ```js
> const [item, setItem] = useStateWithLabel(2, "item");
> ```
>
> ```
> function useStateWithLabel(initialValue, name) {
>   const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
>   useDebugValue(`${name}: ${value}`);
>   return [value, setValue]; 
> }
> ```