# Fail to see the state name in react devtools

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

I have declared some states using `useState` hook. But when I opened the react devtools, I can't these states's names. What I see is `state`, `state` and `state`...... How to display their names? For example, If I declare a state using `const [count,setCount] = useState(0)`. Then I can exactly see the state name `count` in react devtools.

[image]

Comment: Dev tools can't what is the name of the variable that uses the assigned state. You can have multiple variables that are holding the same state.

Comment: look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57659640/is-there-any-way-to-see-names-of-fields-in-react-multiple-state-with-react-dev.  The first answer has displayed the names.